# MySQL - How to determine if my table is stored in RAM?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, memory, innodb

I'm running:

```
MySQL v5.0.67 
InnoDB engine 
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 70MB
```

**Question:** What command can I run to ensure that my entire 50 MB database is stored entirely in RAM?

Comment: I don't suppose "use the `MEMORY` engine" is an acceptable answer?

Comment: I'm not using the MEMORY engine because if the server crashes, I don't want to lose all of my data. Hence why I'm using INNODB, with a RAM value size larger than my dataset. (Good question though)

Answer (score 1):

I am curious about why you want to store the entire table in memory. My guess is that you are not. **The most important thing for me is if your queries are running well** and if you are tied up on disk access. It is also possible that the OS has cached disk blocks that you need if there is memory available. In this case, even though MySQL might not have it in memory, the OS will. If your queries are not running well, and you can do it, I highly recommend adding more memory if you want it all in RAM. If you have slowdowns it is more likely that you are running into contention.

```
show table status
```

will show you some of the information.

If you get the server IO/buffer/cache statistics from

```
show server status
```

and then run a query that requires each row to be accessed (say sum the non empty values from each row using a column that is not indexed) and check to see if any IO has occurred.

I doubt you are caching the entire thing in memory though with only 70MB. You have to take out a lot of cache, temp, and index buffers from that total.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable USE INDEX (PRIMARY)` then InnoDB will put every page of the PRIMARY index into buffer pool (assuming there is enough room in it). If the table has secondary indexes and if you want to load them into the buffer pool, too, then craft a similar query that would read from a secondary index and do the job.